# WCF service - Certificate not reaching server

Tags: wcf, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have a WCF service that I want to use to connect to an external provider's API. The Client constructor in my service looks like this:

```
public partial class SomePortTypeClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<SomeService.ClientPortType>, SomeService.SomePortType
    {
        static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);

        public SomePortTypeClient(string endpointUrl, string username, string password) :
        base(SomePortTypeClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(), SomePortTypeClient.GetEndpointAddress(endpointUrl))
        {
            this.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = username;
            this.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;          
            this.ChannelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine, 
                System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.Root, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "11au2i3h3ir3o1748905");
        }
```

I have three certificates supplied by the service provider, one regular, one intermediate and one root. All three are installed in the personal and trusted root folder on my local computer.

And then the actual implementation of the client and calling the endpoint:

```
SomePortTypeClient someClient = new SomePortTypeClient("https://endpointURL", "username", "password");

var response = someClient.someMethod(someParameter).Result;
```

I have been in contact with the service provider and they can tell that my requests are reaching their server, but without any certificate attached to them. So my question is how can a certificate not be attached when I am clearly setting the certificate in my client constructor per this line: `this.ChannelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.Root, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "11au2i3h3ir3o1748905");`?

Everything is fine with the certificate chain, none of the certificates are expired or anything like that. It's not that there's anything wrong with them, it's that no certificate reaches the server at all. Is there another way to attach certificate(s) to the requests I am sending?

EDIT: I tried calling the service another way using the code below:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certificateCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "13865db1e2cfbed62966c8098bb33384b053e4b5", true);

WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificateCollection[0]);

var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
var yourusername = "user";
var yourpwd = "pwd";

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(){
                RequestUri = new Uri(@"URI"),
                Method = HttpMethod.Post
            };

request.Content = new StringContent(soapRequest.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
request.Headers.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{yourusername}:{yourpwd}")));
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "URI");

HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
            response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Split('>').ToList().ForEach(x=> Console.WriteLine(x));
Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

And this works! So obviously there is nothing wrong with the certificates or the trust chain or anything like that. But why is the certificate attached to the request with the second method, but not the first? Just to clarify the two different methods of adding certificates:

1: `this.ChannelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.Root, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "11au2i3h3ir3o1748905");`

2: `WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificateCollection[0]);`

Comment: Have you ever tried removing the username/password credential, manually adding the Basic authentication header in the HTTP request header(we could use weboperationcontext)?

Comment: If we specify the `clientcredentialtype` is certificate, the basic header might be ignored, which results in the later problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using a certificate to authenticate a client requires a two-way trust relationship, that is, we must both trust the server certificate and make the client-side certificate we provide trusted by the server. Based on the certificate issuing method, we need to install the server's root certificate on the client to establish a chain of trust or install the certificate issued to the server to establish peer trust. In addition, to ensure that the WCF program can use the private key of the certificate, we usually add `Everyone` account to the certificate private key management group.
Please refer to the below document for details.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/working-with-certificates
In addition, if you are not familiar with the configuration of the server, please try to call the service by adding a service reference, which will generate the correct client proxy and configuration file locally.
I would like to know how your client's certificate is issued, and how you provided it to the server to make the server trust your certificate.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Updated original post

Answer (score 0):

WCF service generated code is made up of partial classes that are meant to be "customized".

To fix this specific problem:
I created a new file and added definition to a partial method called `ConfigureEndpoint`:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace MyWebService;

internal partial class MyEndPoint
{
    static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials)
    {
        ((BasicHttpBinding) serviceEndpoint.Binding ).Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
        clientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2("cert filename", "pass");
    }
}
```

The key line is `ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate`. It specifies how to authenticate with the web service.